# Getting a substring in C#?

Tags: c#

This is a simple newbie question.  I could probably figure this out using some complicated method of string like substring and other methods but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Say I have a string in C#:

```
string foo = "&deg;F";
```

What is best way to break that into two different strings where I have "deg" and "F"?

I see what was happening.   stackflow was interpreting the HTML.    It is actually (ampersand)deg(semicolon)F.

Sorry folks it was late when I posted that last night.

Comment: string x = foo.replace("F", "");
string y = foo.replace("°" "");

Comment: What is your criteria to split a string? (also if `String.Substring(start, length)` is too complicated it would be hard to find a solution).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I dunno if it's "complicated" but:

```
string degree = foo[0].ToString();
string f = foo[1].ToString();
```

I feel like you've chosen an overly simple example though. Are you really dealing with a two character string, or are you trying to do something more interesting?

*Update*: Well, I still think you must be trying to do something harder here. But here's another way: (hat tip: @James Didzun)

```
string f = foo.Replace("&deg;","");
string deg = foo.Replace("F", "");
```

Or you could do:

```
string deg = foo.Substring(0, 5);
string f = foo.Substring(5,1);
```

Or:

```
 var deg =  new string(foo.TakeWhile(c => c != 'F').ToArray());
 var f = foo.SkipWhile(c => c != 'F').First().ToString();
```

Or:

```
string[] x = foo.Split(';');
string deg = x[0] + ";";
string f = x[1];
```

Or:

```
string deg = "&deg;"
string f = "F";
```

Personally, I prefer this last approach. Why are you splitting a string that you know the EXACT contents of?

Comment: I updated my issue above.  Sorry for not looking at my post after I posted it.

Comment: I don't know the exact contents.  It was just an example.  Data is from an XML feed from Weather Bug.   Thanks I'll give this a try tonight.

Answer (score 1):

How about this :-)

```
char[] foo = "°F".ToCharArray();

char c1 = foo.First();
char c2 = foo.Last();
```